# Email Parsing to Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to create a script that pulls data from a specific automatic email that comes in into a shared Google Sheet. Currently, we have one built but it pulls emails from the users email and not my email when it is ran. This needs to be pulled from my G Suite email and not the users email. Below is what I have so far. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
function onOpen() {
    const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    let menuItems = [
        {name: 'Gather emails', functionName: 'gather'},
    ];
    spreadsheet.addMenu('DIFM', menuItems);
}

function gather() {
    let messages = getGmail();
    
    let curSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    
    messages.forEach(message => {curSheet.appendRow(parseEmail(message))});
}

function getGmail() {
    const query = "from:domain.com AND subject:subject NOT label:done";

    let threads = GmailApp.search(query,0,10);

    let label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("done");
    if (!label) {label = GmailApp.createLabel("done")};
    
    let messages = [];

    threads.forEach(thread => {
        messages.push(thread.getMessages()[0].getPlainBody());
        label.addToThread(thread)
    })
    
    return messages;
}

function parseEmail(message){
    let parsed = message.replace(/,/g,'')
        .replace(/\n*.+:/g,',')
        .replace(/^,/,'')
        .replace(/\n/g,'')
        .split(',');

    let result = [6,7,8,9,10,11].map(index => parsed[index]);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I've replicated your script & it pulls the message from my actual test account even when the spreadsheet file was just shared to my account. Please add more context/specific details on the issue you're encountering. It looks that there's no issue on your script when tested. The script should be run and authorized by your own Google account for the email messages that will be gathered to come from your account's own email inbox.

Comment: Perhaps you can add SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Added message came from:\n'+ Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()); inside of your gather() function so you can view & check the actual email account where the added messages came from.